# Navigation undefined

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have a problem with my code, I can not redirect to another screen using a button.

I have this error message: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined, js engine: hermes"

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Here is my code :

MainContainer.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// Screens
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import CalendarScreen from './screens/CalendarScreen';
import NotificationsScreen from './screens/NotificationsScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './screens/ProfileScreen';

import AuthScreen from './screens/AuthScreen';

//Screen names
const homeName = "Accueil";
const calendarName = "Calendrier";
const notificationsName = "Notifications";
const profileName = "Profil";

const AuthName = "Authentification";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MainContainer() {
return (
  
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName={homeName}
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;
            let rn = route.name;

            if (rn === homeName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline';

            } else if (rn === calendarName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'calendar' : 'calendar-outline';

            } else if (rn === notificationsName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'notifications' : 'notifications-outline';

            } else if (rn === profileName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'person' : 'person-outline';
            }

            // You can return any component that you like here!
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
          tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'grey',
          tabBarLabelStyle: { paddingBottom: 10, fontSize: 10 },
          tabBarStyle: { padding: 10, height: 70}
        })}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name={homeName} component={HomeScreen} options={({ navigation }) => ({
          headerTitleAlign: 'center'
        })} />
        <Tab.Screen name={calendarName} component={CalendarScreen} options={({ navigation }) => ({
          headerTitleAlign: 'center'
        })} />
        <Tab.Screen name={notificationsName} component={NotificationsScreen} options={({ navigation }) => ({
          headerTitleAlign: 'center'
        })} />
        <Tab.Screen name={profileName} component={ProfileScreen} options={({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitleAlign: 'center'
      })} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>

  );
}

export default MainContainer;
```

WelcomeScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image, Linking } from 'react-native';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

export default function WelcomeScreen({ navigation }) {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Welcome</Text>
      <Text style={styles.description}>Introduction & description</Text>
      <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://hidopi.com/')}>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../../assets/partnership.png')} />
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Nous rejoindre</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')}>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../../assets/user.png')} />
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Se connecter</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.socialMediaButtonsContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.socialMediaButton}>
          <FontAwesome name="facebook" size={24} color="white" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.socialMediaButton}>
          <FontAwesome name="instagram" size={24} color="white" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.socialMediaButton}>
          <FontAwesome name="twitter" size={24} color="white" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  image: {
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 50,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 37,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 50,
    marginBottom: 50,
  },  
  description: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 200,
  },
  buttonsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  button: {
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    flex: 0,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  socialMediaButtonsContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 10,
  },
  socialMediaButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#2196F3',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 50,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
});
```

I don’t know if I did well.
I tried to use props but it didn't work, in my App.js i have a SplashScreen.

Comment: To use `navigation` in your component, this component needs to be in a `Navigator`. That's not the case here

Comment: How should i do this, with a navigation container ?

Comment: You could have a `Stack.Navigator` with the `WelcomeScreen` in it and the TabNav too

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).